# Windows 10 networking on one adapter lost after sleep

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, sleep

I know that similar questions have been asked to this before, but they haven't been of any help to my specific situation. I have multiple adapters on my Win 10 computer. I have a motherboard ethernet adapter that works fine even after sleep and I have another adapter a Solarflare SFN6122F SFP+ with a 10GB fiber sfp installed. The adapter works fine normally, but if I put the computer to sleep it will lose connectivity on this single adapter. The adapter will resume normal operation if I disable it and enable it in the windows adapter menu. It shows as connected with an unidentified network, which isn't concerning since this adapter is only for my LAN backbone and I don't care about DNS or internet connectivity on it, it is only for local connected to a switch with no gateway.
I've disabled allowing windows to save power on the device and made sure it was updated to the latest drivers. I also ran the solarflare diagnostics just for the heck of it and everything checks out fine. Perhaps, it just doesn't like sleep mode since it is really a server nic?

Would love to hear everyone's thoughts on this. If this can't be fixed, is there a way that I can run a script as a windows task whenever sleep is exited, sort of like a startup task to enable and disable it?

Comment: What have you tried ?  Uninstall the driver, and reinstall a newer version. That is normally the best way. If the NIC is not compliant (it is really a server nic)  , remove it and use a different NIC.

Comment: Yeah, I reinstalled the newest driver from the manufacturer's site.

Comment: I suggest using a Workstation card instead of a Server card.